# How do I do an inverted LIKE query in NHibernate?

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

I'm trying to run the following query with NHibernate without using Raw SQL.

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE 'value1 value2 value3' like '%' + MyColumn + '%'
```

Is there any way to do it?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you try something using `linq` or `hql`?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend NHibernate's linq provider easily to have that support. Here's a tutorial about how you do it:
http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com.tr/2010/07/nhibernate-linq-provider-extension.html